# Duplicate count for a column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` like below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['XYZ', 'XYZ', 'XYZ', 'XYZ', 'PQR', 'XYZ', 'XYZ', 'ABC', 'XYZ', 'ABC'], 'B': ['2022-02-16 14:00:31', '2022-02-16 16:11:26', '2022-02-16 17:31:26',
                                                                                           '2022-02-16 22:47:46', '2022-02-17 07:11:11', '2022-02-17 10:43:36', 
                                                                                           '2022-02-17 15:05:11', '2022-02-17 15:07:25', '2022-02-17 15:08:35', 
                                                                                           '2022-02-17 15:09:46'], 'C': [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'])
df


     |   A   |          B           |     C      |  
     +-------+----------------------+------------+
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 14:00:31 |     1      |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 16:11:26 |     0      |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 17:31:26 |     0      |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 22:47:46 |     0      |
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-17 07:11:11 |     1      |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-17 10:43:36 |     0      |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-17 15:05:11 |     0      |
     |  ABC  |  2022-02-17 15:07:25 |     1      |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-17 15:08:35 |     0      |
     |  ABC  |  2022-02-17 15:09:46 |     0      |
     +-------+----------------------+------------+
```

What I want to achieve is that I want to count the number of duplicates for each of the occurences of `XYZ`, `PQR`, `ABC` such that I get an output like below.

```
Expected Output :

     |   A   |          B           |     C      |  Count   |   
     +-------+----------------------+------------+----------+
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 14:00:31 |     1      |    7     |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 16:11:26 |     0      |          |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 17:31:26 |     0      |          |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 22:47:46 |     0      |          |
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-17 07:11:11 |     1      |    1     |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-17 10:43:36 |     0      |          |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-17 15:05:11 |     0      |          |
     |  ABC  |  2022-02-17 15:07:25 |     1      |    2     |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-17 15:08:35 |     0      |          |
     |  ABC  |  2022-02-17 15:09:45 |     0      |          |
     +-------+----------------------+------------+----------+
```

Currently, I'm trying to achieve the same by using the code below but I'm unable to get expected/desired results.

```
one_index = df[df['C'] == 1].index
zero_index = df[df['C'] == 0].index

df.loc[0, 'Count'] = len(df)


     |   A   |          B           |     C      |  Count   |   
     +-------+----------------------+------------+----------+
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 14:00:31 |     1      |    10    |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 16:11:26 |     0      |          |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 17:31:26 |     0      |          |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 22:47:46 |     0      |          |
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-17 07:11:11 |     1      |          |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-17 10:43:36 |     0      |          |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-17 15:05:11 |     0      |          |
     |  ABC  |  2022-02-17 15:07:25 |     1      |          |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-17 15:08:35 |     0      |          |
     |  ABC  |  2022-02-17 15:09:45 |     0      |          |
     +-------+----------------------+------------+----------+
```

So, how can I get count of duplicates for each of the values of column `A` as mentioned ?

EDIT (OPTIONAL):

I would also like to have ID assigned to the groups for the `df` after the count values has been assigned. So, my final dataframe should look like below after ID has been assigned:

```
    |   A   |          B           |     C      |  Count   |   ID  |
    +-------+----------------------+------------+----------+-------+
    |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 14:00:31 |     1      |    7     | ABC_1 |
    |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 16:11:26 |     0      |          |       |
    |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 17:31:26 |     0      |          |       |
    |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 22:47:46 |     0      |          |       |
    |  PQR  |  2022-02-17 07:11:11 |     1      |    1     | ABC_2 |
    |  XYZ  |  2022-02-17 10:43:36 |     0      |          |       | 
    |  XYZ  |  2022-02-17 15:05:11 |     0      |          |       |
    |  ABC  |  2022-02-17 15:07:25 |     1      |    2     | ABC_3 |
    |  XYZ  |  2022-02-17 15:08:35 |     0      |          |       | 
    |  ABC  |  2022-02-17 15:09:45 |     0      |          |       |
    +-------+----------------------+------------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with set empty strings for non `1` values in `C` by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'])

m = df.C.eq(1)
df['Count'] = df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('size').where(m, '')
df.loc[m, 'ID'] = 'ABC_' + pd.RangeIndex(1, m.sum() + 1).astype(str)
df['ID'] = df['ID'].fillna('')
print (df)
     A                   B  C Count     ID
0  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:00:31  1     7  ABC_1
1  XYZ 2022-02-16 16:11:26  0             
2  XYZ 2022-02-16 17:31:26  0             
3  XYZ 2022-02-16 22:47:46  0             
4  PQR 2022-02-17 07:11:11  1     1  ABC_2
5  XYZ 2022-02-17 10:43:36  0             
6  XYZ 2022-02-17 15:05:11  0             
7  ABC 2022-02-17 15:07:25  1     2  ABC_3
8  XYZ 2022-02-17 15:08:35  0             
9  ABC 2022-02-17 15:09:46  0
```

Or:

```
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'])

m = df.C.eq(1)
df['Count'] = df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('size').where(m, '')
df['ID'] = ('ABC_' + df['C'].cumsum().astype(str)).where(m, '')

print (df)
     A                   B  C Count     ID
0  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:00:31  1     7  ABC_1
1  XYZ 2022-02-16 16:11:26  0             
2  XYZ 2022-02-16 17:31:26  0             
3  XYZ 2022-02-16 22:47:46  0             
4  PQR 2022-02-17 07:11:11  1     1  ABC_2
5  XYZ 2022-02-17 10:43:36  0             
6  XYZ 2022-02-17 15:05:11  0             
7  ABC 2022-02-17 15:07:25  1     2  ABC_3
8  XYZ 2022-02-17 15:08:35  0             
9  ABC 2022-02-17 15:09:46  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can we add `ID` as well to the `df` (as a sep column) like `ABC_1`, `ABC_2`, `ABC_3`..., wherever the column `Count` has values `[7, 1, 2]`?

Comment: @user3046211 - Do you think `df['Count'] = (df['A'] + '_' + df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('size').astype(str)).where(df.C.eq(1), '')` ?

Comment: Uh, no - that results in like `XYZ_7, PQR_1, ABC_2` respectively. In lieu of this, I just need ID in a separate column to be as `ABC_1, ABC_2, ABC_3` respectively.

Comment: @user3046211 - So need `df['New'] = (df['A'] + '_' + df.groupby('A').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)` ?

Comment: Still no, I have edited my question now accordingly, so now I think it should be clear

Answer (score 1):

Use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['Count'] = df.loc[df['C'].eq(1), 'A'].map(df['A'].value_counts())
```

output:

```
     A                   B  C  Count
0  XYZ 2022-02-16 14:00:31  1    7.0
1  XYZ 2022-02-16 16:11:26  0    NaN
2  XYZ 2022-02-16 17:31:26  0    NaN
3  XYZ 2022-02-16 22:47:46  0    NaN
4  PQR 2022-02-17 07:11:11  1    1.0
5  XYZ 2022-02-17 10:43:36  0    NaN
6  XYZ 2022-02-17 15:05:11  0    NaN
7  ABC 2022-02-17 15:07:25  1    2.0
8  XYZ 2022-02-17 15:08:35  0    NaN
9  ABC 2022-02-17 15:09:46  0    NaN
```